# How to make a mute command in dSharpPlus

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I want to create a command for a discord bot with which you can mute the user, but when the command is processed, the bot answers "The application is not responding"

```
internal class SlashCommandModule : ApplicationCommandModule
    {
        [SlashCommand("mute", "Mute user")]
        public async Task Mute(InteractionContext ctx, [Option("user", "User for mute")] DiscordUser user)
        {
            var member = (DiscordMember)user;
            await member.SetMuteAsync(true);
            await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource, new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder().WithContent($"Muted {user.Username}"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here might be with using the `DiscordUser` type as your input for `user`. `DiscordUser` is not a string but rather a snowflake object, so you cannot directly cast a string into a `DiscordUser` and then cast this into a `DiscordMember`.

Instead, you can try getting the username as a string and then finding the user with `ctx.Guild.SearchMembersAsync()`. This will return all results that are similar to the username you enter and will capture the most likely result for us to cast into a `DiscordMember` using `ctx.Guild.GetMemberAsync()`.

```
internal class SlashCommandModule : ApplicationCommandModule
    {
        [SlashCommand("mute", "Mute user")]
        public async Task Mute(InteractionContext ctx,
          [Option("user", "User for mute")] string user) //user becomes a string
        {
            ulong userIdForMute = ctx.Guild.SearchMembersAsync(user).Result[0].Id;
            DiscordMember memberForMute = ctx.Guild.GetMemberAsync(userIdForMute);
            await memberForMute.SetMuteAsync(true);
            await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
             new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder().WithContent($"Muted <@{userIdForMute}>"));
             //@ them using their ID by using <@id>
        }
    }
```

This may inadvertently capture the wrong user if someone enters only a partial username, so another way you can do this would be to require user IDs (accepted as a string) and try to cast that to a ulong.

Comment: Just to add a little clarity to one point; when you accept the option `user` it is being input as a string by the user, so I believe where it is failing is that DSharp+ is not catching an exception for converting this string into a `DiscordUser` in a way that it notifies you about, leading to no returned response from the bot.